# Producing a data.frame for presence/absence for each raster cell in R

Tags: r, distribution, spatial, modeling

G'day,

I have a data set I am trying to run a boosted regression tree model on with code:

```
pa.brt.m <- gbm.step(data=data, gbm.x = 5:15, gbm.y = 2, 
                     family = "bernoulli", tree.complexity = 5, 
                     learning.rate = 0.01, bag.fraction = 0.5)
```

As it goes about it's business, it returns the error:

> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

I am wondering what is going on and how I can fix this? This error seems to stop the function and I don't get the rest of the output I would expect. Can anyone provide some insight into what is going on?

Comment: Where are you working? Rstudio or the R console?

Comment: Reproducible example with sample data please?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the plotting area 
is too small to put the margins 
(margins have an absolute dimension: 
they will not shrink), 
especially when you want many small
plots.

If you had issued a command such as `par(mfrow=c(100,100))`,
you need to undo it, e.g., by closing the plot window.
This is the most probable cause of the problem.

You can also try to enlarge ("maximize") the plot window.

You can also try to change the margins, e.g. with 
`par(mar=c(0,0,0,0),oma=c(0,0,0,0))`.

You can also try to divert the plot to a file,
with sufficiently large dimensions.

```
pdf("a.pdf", width=100, height=100)
...
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent, 
I figured out that I just had to remove all NA values from the data set before running gbm.step(). 
The info you have provided will prove valuable in the future, I am sure. Thanks for your reply.
Regards,
Adam